# DotNetNuke: Social Links for Blog Module

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, blogs, social-media

What is the best method for adding social links to each blog entry?

I could use sample code of adding links to the ascx files or I am even able to pay a little for a module that will do it.

I will have parent and child portals.

edit:  I've updated the module and checked the social bookmarking options.  However it did not appear?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upgrade to the newest version of the Blog module and then under module options for the blog you can check "Enable Social Bookmarks". Alternatively with an older version of the Blog module you can follow the instructions outlined [here](http://www.wwwcoder.com/parentid/224/tabid/68/type/art/site/6525/default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is already built into the core Blog module.  The [blogs at DotNetNuke.com](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/Default.aspx) all have social links, and Antonio has [a blog post](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1865/Upcoming-Blog-Features-Part-1-Social-Bookmarks.aspx) saying they'll be in 3.4.1, with the current version being 3.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I use ADDTHIS.COM and place the code snippet it gives me in the container.